# Function list in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Please help me with this issue. How can I display a list of functions like. these ones:[image: Screenshot]
When I press *tab* or *ctrl + space* I only get a list with words which I've used in the file but not list with functions. I use Python syntax

Will be very thankful for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Sublime Package Control to install a python auto completion package like python completions.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Completions

In sublime text,

1. Preferences -> Package Control
2. Select install package from the popup menu
3. Search for Python Completion
4. Click on it
5. After installation just change the syntax to python from view menu

Edit:
   If you don't see the package control option in Preferences menu, go to tools and select install package control.

Comment: Sorry, my reputation is too small for upvoting but I marked the answer :) 
Thanks again

Comment: No worries, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Anaconda plugin](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) that comes also with other perks.

Important to have also the follow configs yo have it working:

1. **Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings**

```
    "auto_complete": true,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,
    "show_definitions": true,
    "tab_completion": false,
```

1. **Packages/User/Python.sublime-settings**

```
    "auto_complete_triggers": [{"selector": "source.python - string - comment - constant.numer
```

Answer (score 0):

install jedi python autocompletion from the package installer , this will put most function options to choose from, such as the random module with the random function, this will show you all the options once you type a . after the function

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32622919)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).